# Error with secondary axis and date x axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to make a graph with a secondary axis so as to have a nicer representation of the data. Primary y axis is a conversion and the secondary y axis a bar chart which shows volume.

My dataframe is:

```
df
     date_nk            channel_sk   dauli     dau  dauliPdau
  2018-09-01    mobile_app|android  271166  319648   0.848327
  2018-09-02    mobile_app|android  306497  362779   0.844859
  2018-09-03    mobile_app|android  311189  365406   0.851625
  2018-09-04    mobile_app|android  302114  354216   0.852909
  2018-09-05    mobile_app|android  301301  352287   0.855271
```

And my graph code to plot my graph with secondary y axis is:

```
sns.set()
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(15,8))

st = fig.suptitle("Total active users log in (DAULI) / Total active users 
(DAU)", fontsize=15)
st.set_y(0.95)

# First graph
ax1.plot(df['date_nk'],df['dauliPdau'], 
color='darkblue',marker='o',label='mobile_app|android')

ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

ax1v = ax1.twinx()

ax1v.bar(df['date_nk'] , df['dauliPdau'])
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('< M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')

Answer (score 0):

1. If I run your code, there is no error; the following plot is generated:

[image]

2. I don't see any subtraction anywhere in your posted code, so it is completely unclear, where this error message might be thrown; probably in a part you did not post.
3. I don't know what you mean by "conversion" and "volume" which you say are shown on the primary and secondary y-axis. But in your code you put the same data in both plot commands, the line- and the bar-plot:
   `ax1.plot(df['date_nk'], df['dauliPdau'], ...`
   `ax1v.bar(df['date_nk'], df['dauliPdau'])`
4. Besides that I'd like to mention that you do not need parantheses around `ax1` in the `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(...)` line.